# Dependencies to Generate OpenAPI Server Code for Spring Boot

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator

I have an existing Spring Boot 2.7.5 project. I decided to start using OpenAPI to build out the rest of the project's API.

My OpenAPI spec is version 3.0.3

I added the following to my pom file to generate the server code:

**Build Plugin**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>
                            ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml
                        </inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <apiPackage>com.xxx.yyy.zzz.api</apiPackage>
                        <modelPackage>com.xxx.yyy.zzz.model</modelPackage>
                        <supportingFilesToGenerate>
                            ApiUtil.java
                        </supportingFilesToGenerate>
                        <configOptions>
                            <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Dependencies**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

After doing so I kept getting errors such as:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal [org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile [(default-compile) on project [xxx-svc: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /C:/xxx/xxx-svc/target/generated-sources/openapi/src/main/java/com/xxx/yyy/zzz/model/XxxTypeNew.java:[49,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method requiredMode()
[ERROR]   location: @interface io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema
```

To solve the issue I added an additional dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

What I cannot understand is why do I have to add this dependency?
I if I am using the same version for both the openapi generator and dependency, why would the code generated not compile without one more dependency?

If this is a non-idiomatic way to use OpenApi with SpringBoot I am open to explore alternatives.

Comment: You shouldn't have to add additional dependencies. The dependencies should automatically be set by the generator depending on your settings.  Are you by chance using IntelliJ?  If so, have you enabled annotation processing?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the springfox-swagger2 dependency which will pull all the Swagger Types :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The generator generates Java classes based on textual templates, it does not manipulate Java code, and so does not need swagger dependencies.

The templates are found here : https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java

Comment: Hi Lucas, do you mean I do not need openapi-generator as a dependency and should swap it with springfox-swagger2?

Comment: @Lucas this is wrong.  The OP did not specify he was using springfox for his documentation provider.  By default, the documentationProvider for the Spring generator is `springdoc`.  Adding this introduces an unnecessary extra dependency just to bring in transitive dependencies.  OP, don't do this.